# Is there any tutorial for Ship Simulator Extremes?

Tags: ship-simulator-extremes

I just bought Ship Simulator Extremes but I can't find any tutorial.

It's pretty annoying and hard to play without knowing how to play because I haven't played any ship simulator before. :D

Is there any tutorial for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is!

Go into play, then single missions, and then click Tutorial Mission 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there seem to be a tutorial mission. I never played the game myself, but here I found a video on Youtube, maybe it can help: